# View disappears that slides up when textfield is selected, disappears when keyboard is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to replicate whatsapp, imessage etc. keyboard going up with the send button/textfield sitting right on top of it
I have one TableView and a container view that holds the textfield and the send button.

Everytime i tap on the textfield the container view goes up and "sits" on the keyboard, BUT once i start typing the container view disappears and goes to the bottom where initially was. Why is this happening??

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
messageTextfield.delegate=self
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {

   let duration = sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let beginningFrame = (sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let endFrame = (sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let deltaY = endFrame.origin.y - beginningFrame.origin.y

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
        self.containerView.frame.origin.y += deltaY
    }, completion: nil)

}


@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification) {
    let userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any] = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
    self.containerView.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height

}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
}



func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){

   super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you increase y position of container view in both keyboard show/hide , so Change to this

```
 @objc  func handleKeyboardDidShow (notification: NSNotification)
 {
    let keyboardRectAsObject = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue

    var keyboardRect = CGRect.zero

    keyboardRectAsObject.getValue(&keyboardRect)

    self.containerViewBotcon.constant = -1 * keyboardRect.height 

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {

       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })

} 

@objc func handleKeyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification)
{

    self.containerViewBotcon.constant = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,animations: {

       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })

}
```

Comment: It actually makes it worse! Now not only the view still disappears after the keyboard is tapped, but it also goes lower and lower everytime the textfield is selected

Comment: Same result! I dont think thats the problem, as with my solution the keyboard acts as intended, the problem is the containerview(cointaining textfield and send button) that slides down to initial position when the keyboard is tapped.

Comment: try to comment view.endEditing(true)

Comment: I have done that, i also deleted the whole touchesBegan. Nothing changes..

Comment: y you increase y when keyboard is going to hide    self.containerView.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164421/discussion-between-do2-and-sh-khan).